# Convert sql to dql symfony

Tags: php, sql, symfony, dql

I would like to convert this request in sql to dql , need a little help.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS nb_files 
FROM palettes 
    JOIN files_palettes ON palettes.id = files_palettes.palettes_id 
GROUP BY files_palettes.palettes_id 
ORDER BY nb_files DESC
```

**Edit**

The attempted query.

```php
public function findSaveByPagesByFilters()
{
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    $select = " SELECT  COUNT (p) AS nb_files";       
    $from = " FROM App\Entity\Palettes p ";
    $join = "JOIN p.files f ";
    $on = " ON p.id = f.palettes ";
    $groupBy = " GROUP BY f.p";
    $orderBy = " ORDER BY f.name DESC ";
       
    $dqlQuery = $select . $from  . $join . $on . $groupBy;
    //dd($dqlQuery);
    $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
        $dqlQuery
    );

  
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Here's the message sent by insomnia :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 74: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'

Comment: SO is not actually a code conversion service. The best way is to have a try yourself and then if you have problems, show us your attempt and what you are trying to convert. That way we feel less like we are being used as a free coding service

Comment: Learn DQL step by step, try join palettes with file_palettes, then try to group by files_palettes, add `count` and `orderBy`.
Stack Overflow is not fiverr, the point is to make questions that can help future users.

Comment: Just checking, you actually want to count the number of files per pallettes, right? Do you actually need the `SELECT *` part ? Or just `SELECT COUNT(*)` is enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're within the context of a repository, so in which case I'd advise using the [Doctrine Query Builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/query-builder.html), it'd help simplify your code flow, and probably would help you with SQL conversions in the future.

To answer this specific problem, you'd probably want to do something like the following:

```
public function findSaveByPagesByFilters()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->innerJoin('p.files', 'f', Query\Expr\Join::ON, 'p.id = f.pallets')
        ->select(['*', 'count(p.id)'])
        ->groupBy('f.p')
        ->orderBy('f.name', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: The `Join::ON` is automatically appended by the `p.files` association mapping, unless manually specifying the Entity association. `f.p` is not referenceable, it  should be `p.id` as the `INNER JOIN` limits the records to those matching the `files_palettes.palettes_id` reference. Lastly when using the ORM DQL/QueryBuilder, `Join::ON` should be `Join:WITH`.

Comment: Thank you very much thurston, I would like to count the number of results to display it

Answer (score -1):

```
$dql = "SELECT p as palette, count(p.id) as cnt FROM App\Entity\Palettes p " .
    "JOIN p.files f GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY cnt DESC";
    ;
```

Thx Alexis !!